# "severity":"WARNING","message":"Request has invalid method. GET

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Minimal code:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'My error message');
});
```

When I run

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I get the following link:

> ✔  functions[us-central1-test]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/project/us-central1/test).

Upon clicking it, I get the following error:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-test"
>  {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request has invalid method. GET"}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-test" in ~1s
```

I was expecting `failed-precondition` and `My error message`. What am I doing wrong?

**PS: I've have checked other answers but I think there's something wrong in my code.**

Comment: The problem was I was invoking callable function through HTTP (which requires a protocol to be implemented, like I must pass `data` to it). However, the above code works well using the Firebase Client SDK callable helper.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to add "return" before your "throw new"?

I'm having a similar issue myself, but from what I understand the data should be returned from a promise.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You don't require a `return` when throwing an error.